# Assistant getting ZeroClipboard to work

Tags: jquery, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I have read the wiki in the plugin page, searched and researched 
but i still cant get zropClipboard to work...

- i am not getting any javascript error...
- the text is being alerted correctly but wont get to my clipboard

This is my code:

```
var clip = new ZeroClipboard($('.copythis'));

clip.on('load', function(client) {
    // alert( "movie is loaded" );
});

clip.on('complete', function(client, args) {
    alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + args.text );
});

clip.on('mouseover', function(client) {
    // alert("mouse over");
});

clip.on('mouseout', function(client) {
    // alert("mouse out");
});

clip.on( 'mousedown', function(client) {
    var copythis = '#' + $(this).attr('cliptarget');
    var copytext = $(copythis).val();
    client.setText(copytext); // ALSO TRIED: clip.setText(copytext);
    alert(copytext); // THIS ALERTS THE RIGHT TEXT
});

clip.on( 'mouseup', function(client) {
    // alert("mouse up");
});
```

I really want to get it to work... Would apreaciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `mousedown` with [`dataRequested`](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md#datarequested).

> On mousedown, the flash object will check and see if the clipText has
>   been set. If it hasn't, then it will fire off a dataRequested event.
>   If the html object has data-clipboard-text or data-clipboard-target
>   then ZeroClipboard will take care of getting the data. However if it
>   hasn't been set, then it will be up to you to clip.setText from that
>   method. Which will complete the loop.

Comment: OMG! it works - finally - a lot of wasted hours. Your the man @CD thanks a lot.